# Can I go for a DDR4 RAM?

Tags: memory, cpu, dell-inspiron, ddr

I am having Dell Inspiron 15 3542 touch.

I just have a ***single*** RAM slot.
Currently I have DDR3 RAM whose details are as follows:

```
H/W path      Device      Class          Description
====================================================
/0/1/0                    memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600
```

---

My processor information is as follows:
Intel® Core™ i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4

To be more specific:

```
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-4210U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 2700 MHz 1: 799 MHz 2: 799 MHz 3: 800 MHz 4: 800 MHz
```

I wish to go for an 8GB DDR4 RAM.
Any kind of guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the capacity of your motherboard.

Comment: Your CPU can handle 16GB of DDR3 RAM, so your motherboard should have 2 RAM slots, one is already occupied with 4GB DDR3-1600, and the other one is still available. So, technically, you can go up to 16GB of DDR3L RAM. You have two options a DDR3-1600 or DDR3-1333 either one of them will work fine with your system. just be sure to have the same RAMs specs on both slots.

Comment: iSR5 i have mentioned that my laptop has single RAM slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, Intel don't support DDR4 until 6th Core generation.

Comment: Additionally, the physical specs of DDR3 slots don't allow a DDR4 SODIMM to be inserted, the notch is offset differently. Very unlikely for a motherboard to support multiple DDR standards, although the compatible clock speeds within the standard vary widely from motherboard to motherboard